# Дублировать значения из combobox1 в combobox2

Tags: c#

Есть combobox1 и combobox2. В combobox1 уже есть значения, необходимо их дублировать в combobox2. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
comboBox2.Items.AddRange(comboBox1.Items.Cast<Object>().ToArray());
```